# Add the view mode to the CSS classes used for the body

Tags: 7, theming, bootstrap-theme

Is it possible to add the view mode used for a display into the body class?

At the moment, the view mode is being inserted into one of the region classes, but I would like to add it also to the body class. This would allow me to change the page to full width depending on the view mode.

I am using the Bootstrap theme.

Comment: Are you talking about view mode of any content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sub theme of [bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) then you can possibly add class to body tag of the node.

Go to `SubThemeDirectory/`and open `template.php` and add this hook_preprocess_html()

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $vars['body_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'mode-' . $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$node->nid]['#view_mode']; // Node ID class
  }
}
```

I hope this'll at least give an idea how to add class attribute.

Comment: It doesn't matter what theme you are using, you should be able to add a body class in any theme.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This looks good, but how can I get $node ($node->nid) from inside the function? If I know this I can get it to work.

Comment: @Ben, I already added `if ($node = menu_get_object())`, it'll load all objects into `$node` so you can access any object of the node like `$node->nid`. See more about [menu_get_object()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7.x)

Comment: @usmanjutt84 - Yes, you are absolutely right. I was trying to access $node from above your part of the code. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you